# How to make sure SFTP session always close at the end of the spring-batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-batch

My application is based on spring-boot 2.1.6 equipped with spring-batch (chunks approach) and spring-integration to handle the SFTP.

High level functionality is to fetch data from DB, generate a text file then send it through SFTP and this task run every 30 mins.

This application already running in production for some time, but if I see the logs there are error about **ssh_msg_disconnect 11 idle connection**. It will keep like that until I restart the app.

Below is my application code :

SftpConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
public class SftpConfig {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        final DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost(applicationProperties.getSftp().getHost());
        factory.setUser(applicationProperties.getSftp().getUser());
        factory.setPassword(applicationProperties.getSftp().getPass());
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);

        return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel", adviceChain = "retryAdvice")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        final SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(this.sftpSessionFactory());
        handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(applicationProperties.getSftp().getPath()));
        handler.setFileNameGenerator((final Message<?> message) -> {
            if (message.getPayload() instanceof File) {
                return ((File) message.getPayload()).getName();
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("File expected as payload.");
            }
        });

        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice() {
        final RequestHandlerRetryAdvice advice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
        final RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        final SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(NumberConstants.FIVE);
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        advice.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);

        return advice;
    }

    @MessagingGateway
    public interface UploadGateway {

        @Gateway(requestChannel = "toSftpChannel")
        void upload(File file);
    }

}
```

step for sending file to sftp

```java
@Autowired
UploadGateway uploadGateway;

private boolean uploadToSharedFolderSuccess(final PaymentStatus paymentStatus, final String strLocalTmpPath) {
        try {
            final File fileLocalTmpFullPath = new File(strLocalTmpPath);
            uploadGateway.upload(fileLocalTmpFullPath);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            paymentStatus.setStatus(ProcessStatus.ERROR.toString());
            paymentStatus.setRemark(StringUtil.appendIfNotEmpty(paymentStatus.getRemark(),
                    "Error during upload to shared folder - " + e.getMessage()));
        }
        return !StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(ProcessStatus.ERROR.toString(), paymentStatus.getStatus());
    }
```

From the error, I know that seems like I opened too many connection. But I'm not sure how to check if the connection are closed every end of the spring-batch.

Comment: Basically @ServiceActivator is a passive component and it obtains a session from SessionFactory on demand. For next call should bring a new session anyway, since you don't use a isSharedSession flag. I Suggest set this flag true.

For reference look the properties  documentation 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.M3/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-session-factory-properties

Comment: Don't use a `CachingSessionFactory` if you want the session to be physically closed after use.

Comment: @Dhiren, isSharedSession flag is there and set as true during init the session factory.. about on demand thing, is there any article that can support the statement?

Comment: @Gary Russell, then what should I use? Any suggestion?

Comment: If you want to sperate session for each call then use DefaultSessionFactory otherwise CachingSessionFactory. Depends on your usecase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't wrap the session factory in a `CachingSessionFactory`, the session will be closed after each use.

```
@Bean
public DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory() {
    final DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    factory.setHost(applicationProperties.getSftp().getHost());
    factory.setUser(applicationProperties.getSftp().getUser());
    factory.setPassword(applicationProperties.getSftp().getPass());
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);

    return factory;
}
```